# Convert date and time coulmns to timestamp

Tags: pandas

I have two columns in my data set Date and Time and I want to convert both columns to a time stamp meanning to have dat month year hour minute and seconds I pased the date and time and I can index each ome alone but I nedd both of them in the index and help would be appreciated.

```
df= pd.read_csv('Data',parse_dates=['Date',' Time'])
#I end up having both coulmns but I want to merge them in one as a time stamp and then index them 

df.set_index('Date_ Time') 
# it says that there is no Time in columns 

#any ideas?
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you update your post with the 5 first lines of your csv file, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If add `[]` to `[['Date','Time']]` :

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data',parse_dates=[['Date',' Time']])
```

then your solution working well.

```
df.set_index('Date_ Time')
```

Or use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data',parse_dates=[['Date',' Time']], index_col=[0])

df = pd.read_csv('Data',parse_dates=[['Date',' Time']], index_col=['Date_ Time'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your csv looks like:

```
Date,Time
2021-07-09,11:00:00
2021-07-09,12:00:00
2021-07-09,13:00:00
2021-07-09,14:00:00
2021-07-09,15:00:00
```

You can use this method to create a DateTimeIndex:

```
# Read csv without parse dates
df = pd.read_csv('Data')
print(df)

         Date      Time
0  2021-07-09  11:00:00
1  2021-07-09  12:00:00
2  2021-07-09  13:00:00
3  2021-07-09  14:00:00
4  2021-07-09  15:00:00

# Combine columns and set index
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']))
print(df)

                           Date      Time
2021-07-09 11:00:00  2021-07-09  11:00:00
2021-07-09 12:00:00  2021-07-09  12:00:00
2021-07-09 13:00:00  2021-07-09  13:00:00
2021-07-09 14:00:00  2021-07-09  14:00:00
2021-07-09 15:00:00  2021-07-09  15:00:00
```